# Android: Infinite loop in proc folder

Tags: android, android-file

I am developing file manager application in Android. In my app, I have one button which shows number of files and number of folders for every folders. I use recursive function and my function works except proc folder. Functions goes into an infinite loop for this folder.

I guess there are temporary files in this folder but I do not know how to handle this condition.

I don't get any warning in log but I see this path in the log.

```
proc/self/task/20561/cwd/sys/devices/platform/omap/omap_l3_noc.0/subsystem/devices/power.0
```

How can I handle this temporarily files?

My function:

```
private void iterate(String directory) {
        File dir = new File(directory);

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {


                size = size + listFile[i].length();

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

                    numberOfFolders++;
                    iterate(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

                } else {

                    numberOfFiles++;

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Give us some code, anyways, checking if the folder name is not 'proc' can do the job?

Comment: I can put my code but it very simple recursive. I can check folder name if it is proc but there are same apps in the market which shows number of files in proc folder.

Comment: Even very simple code can have errors or info about the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I don't know if is the best ideea, but you can count the number of times you called that function for the same folder, and if the counter is greater than a value like 10000 go to next folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid `/proc` `/dev` (sometimes) and `/sys` and you'll be fine. `/proc` and `/sys` definitely have recursions, and I've seen them in `/dev` too.

Basically avoid all fake (what's the correct word?) filesystems.

You can't detect this recursion (simply anyway) because as you've seen the path is recursive, it is not like following `..` then going back into a child of the parent, the paths for two different levels in the recursion are DIFFERENT, where as `./A/B/C` and `./A/../A/../A/B/../B/./././C` are technically the same.

BTW why are you scanning these files? They're not real! What use could you have to be *scanning* them?

Put that in the question please!

**Addendum**

Run `mount` in a terminal and do not touch anything that isn't from a device. That should certainly help. 'cept `/dev/pts`.

For example, I could use `sshfs` to mount my other laptop's FS to this laptops, and I could mount this laptop's fs within my computers, and my computer's fs to my other laptops, now if I scan without caution recursion across 3 computers!

Comment: I want to show number of folders, number of files and size for these folders.

Comment: @SavasCinar Have a read about the unix file system and mounting stuff, you can probably be safe if you just avoid /proc /dev and /sys anyway, for example /proc/sda is your primary hard disk, if you read that you are reading bytes from your hard disk! /dev/sda1 is the first partition, file system programs read these "files" to report back lists of items inside directories and stuff. Also no meaningful count or size can come from /proc, /dev and /sys, they're not on disks, Linux just tells you they're there. /proc/cpuinfo "appears" to contain CPU info for example.

Comment: Thank you Alec for explanation. I will avoid these three folders.